# Calling images from the database on the view is out of MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, design-patterns

I've created a model for the base table, the one with the infos.
Then another model for the images table, and extended it to my generic images model, which is the following:

```
class Application_Model_GenericImages extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
   public function getImage($relCol, $id) {
     $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter();
     return $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM {$_name} 
                           WHERE {$_name}.{$relCol} = '{$id}'");
   }

}
```

The model for the images table is like:

```
class Application_Model_ImagesTable extends Application_Model_GenericImages {
   protected $_name = 'images_table';
}
```

Then on the controller i do the following:

```
$infoTable = $this->view->infoTable = new Application_Model_InfoTable();
/* I haven't made the info table here because there's no point to... */
$imagesModel = $this->view->imagesModel = new Application_Model_ImagesTable();
```

And finally on the view it's like:

```
foreach ($infoTable->fetchAll() as $info) {
  //Print Some Info
  $image = $this->imageModel->getImage('info_id', $info->id);
}
```

Is this wrong? If it is, how bad is this and how's the right way to do it?

Comment: The question make no sense. There are a lot of things wrong with your code (including possible SQL injections). Also, you shouldn't be using `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` as base for your model layer structures. Model is not a DB abstraction.